# bash create dummy files and folders based on real files

Tags: bash, loops, replace

so I need a simple bash script to create dummy files and folders based on contents of an actual folder.
here is what I got so far

```
dir=/mnt/TV
dummy_dir=/home/bob/Desktop/dummy

for d in `ls $dir`; do
  mkdir "$dummy_dir/$(basename $d)"
done
for f in `ls -a $dir`; do
  touch "$dummy_dir/$(basename $f)"
done
```

but it is not working properly.. thanks

Comment: Can you be more specific than “it is not working properly”?

Comment: I guess the output of "ls $dir" is not what you expect it to be. Check your aliases?

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using `` `cmd` ``, `$(cmd)` is the new style and should be used if possible, it's clearer and can be nested too. However I wouldn't use either.

The issue your having is, I suspect, to do with you're mkdir, which requires that all the top level directories exist before creating the base ie

```
mkdir /tmp/path/here
```

requires /tmp/path to exist unless you use the -p flag, which creates the whole tree regardless of what currently exists.

Another issue you will find is that hidden files and directories will be created as files and non-hidden files and directories will be created as directories, regardless of the type of file in the origional directory.

A better way to do this would be to use find. eg

```
dir=/mnt/TV
dummy_dir=/home/bob/Desktop/dummy

find $dir -type d -printf '%P\n' | \
    while read dir; do 
        [[ -d "$dummy_dir/$dir" ]] || mkdir -p "$dummy_dir/$dir"
    done

find $dir -type f -printf '%P\n' | \
     while read file; do
        [[ -f "$dummy_dir/$file" ]] || touch "$dummy_dir/$file"
     done
```

The first find command will print out the path relative to $dir of all directories that are a subdirectory of $dir. These are then piped into the while loop which tests to see if the directory exists in the dummy_dir and creates it if it isn't.

The second find command will do the same for files.

Note: this will completely ignore sym links sockets or any other file that isn't a directory or regular file.

If this does not do what you want, please update your question to include much more detail.

Comment: Note, that with your example, if a directory or file name exists with embedded whitespace, it will break.

Comment: thank you this does what I need.
I just need dummy files to test file renaming scripts.

Answer (score 0):

```
cp -pvr /mnt/TV /home/bob/Desktop/dummy
```

If you are trying to achieve anything more than this, specify it in your question.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something this would create actual copies though, not dummies.